# Dynamic Third-party Namespaced Module Loading with Yarn, Typescript and Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundle, yarnpkg, webpack-hmr

I have an agnostic application that can serve any private side developed project in a sandboxed container.

Until now, I had no issue because all 3rd party modules (or bundle) were explicitly defined in my `package.json` and explicitly loaded in my code with full string value.

Like this :

```
import Bundle from '@company/bundle';
// ...
```

But now, my goal is to install and load those modules dynamically.
I've already do the 'install' part, but I need to achieve this:

```
(async () => {
    const something = ['/bundle']; // here for example but getted from a config file
    for (const bundleName of something) {
        const Bundle = await import(`@company${bundleName}`)
        Bundle.doStuff();
    }
})();
```

How do I achieve this ? Node js middleware ? Custom webpack plugin/loader ? bundle-loader ?

Comment: To answer my needs I've created a webpack plugin: https://github.com/bios21/dynamic-vendor-webpack-plugin